# I get the following error when i build my project in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

C:\Users\Faheem\Desktop\dashboard>flutter build apk --profile

Building with sound null safety

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.2/lib/src/storage.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.2/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:9:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-3.3.13/lib/src/firebase_auth_web_recaptcha_verifier_factory.dart:7:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.2/lib/src/utils.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core_web-1.6.2/lib/firebase_core_web.dart:10:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
import 'dart:js';
^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:13:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html' as html;
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:5:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';
^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/js_url_strategy.dart:79:48: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
external ui.VoidCallback addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:194:3: Error: Type 'html.Location' not found.
html.Location get _location => html.window.location;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:196:3: Error: Type 'html.History' not found.
html.History get _history => html.window.history;
^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:199:28: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
void addPopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/url_strategy.dart:204:31: Error: Type 'html.EventListener' not found.
void removePopStateListener(html.EventListener fn) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:7:7: Error: Type 'AnchorElement' not found.
final AnchorElement _urlParsingNode = AnchorElement();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter_web_plugins/lib/src/navigation/utils.dart:20:7: Error: Type 'Element' not found.
final Element? _baseElement = document.querySelector('base');
^^^^^^^
../../runtime/vm/zone.cc: 94: error: Out of memory.
version=2.16.2 (stable) (Tue Mar 22 13:15:13 2022 +0100) on "windows_x64"
pid=3640, thread=8308, isolate_group=main(00000000053F0BE0), isolate=(nil)(0000000000000000)
isolate_instructions=3e90000, vm_instructions=7ff6304d5460

pc 0x00007ff6306dd222 fp 0x000000000a36eb20 Dart_IsPrecompiledRuntime+0x21cd22
-- End of DumpStackTrace
=== Crash occured when compiling package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/hierarchy/hierarchy_node.dart_ClassHierarc* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildProfile'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
flutter clean
flutter packages get
dart pub get
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, I recommend starting a new project and moving your code and pubspec.yaml files there.

Comment: brother it works on flutter web

Comment: The error appears to be because of missing 'dart' and 'html' imports, if you have added the imports correctly, I don't understand why it wouldn't work :(

Comment: I used  this import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as HTML;  because import 'dart:html';
 wont work with android

Comment: no one helps me here!